# After merging a branch to trunk in subsvn, will you delete the branch?

Tags: svn

I am wondering if i should delete the merged branch.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you merge a branch into trunk using "svn merge --reintegrate", you are recommended to delete the branch. If you want to do further development in that branch, you should "re-branch", effectively create a new branch with the same name, but rooted at the same revision as you merged the branch into trunk.

Read more about [svn merge --reintegrate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html).

EDIT: updated link

Comment: but if i delete the branch, how can i know when the trunk is merged, as subsvn doesn't show the merge path.

Comment: You will have a commit message saying something like "reintegrated branch foo into trunk", and trunk will have svn:mergeinfo properties showing what you have merged.

Comment: @JesperE, Thanks for the info. really helpful. it's a pitty the Revision Graph doesn't draw the merge path.

Comment: Yup, Subversion doesn't do merging very well.

Comment: Link in answer is dead: http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you created the branch for in the first place. A branch is usually used for maintaining a released or soon-to-be-released version of software, so in general, no, you would not delete it. Even if you do, it is still there taking up space (its just no longer visible in the current version), so unless you have a great need to delete it, I would keep it around.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep it. The SVN tree gives you a lot of history about your source code repository.

Answer (score -3):

No, if you don't have disk space problem. Who knows what will be needed tomorrow.

Comment: What does disk space have to do with anything? Deleting a branch does not affect the size of the repository.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know.

Comment: For reference: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html - See the note about "Cheap Copies"